# How to convert android library project with resources to jar?

Tags: android, jar, sdk

Hi I had created an android library project. Now I want to distribute my library to others without showing my code. I tried it with converting to jar. But its not working because I used resources in the library project. So is there any method to convert library project with resources to jar file ?? or How can I hide my java code in the project ??? please help me with some examples, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a jar from your project and then create a new project and add your resources to that project also put your jar in libs folder of new project. leave the manifest file as it is.

You can see the example in google_play_service_lib which is in extra folder in your sdk.

Comment: I tried this way but it force closed after intagration

Comment: No it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can  convert that library file to jar file by running some commands in command prompt :

```
jar -cvf jar-file input-file(s)
```

jar-file is the file name which will be created so it should have extension .jar
For example

jar -cvf convertedjar.jar myppackagename

Please refer this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html